# Is the equivalent of onMessage of javax.jms.MessageListener in Solace Java API PersistentMessageReceiver receiveAsync method?

Tags: spring-boot, solace

To consume messages from a Persistent queue in an old monolithic app, I had used `javax.jms.MessageListener#onMessage(javax.jms.Message)` 10 years ago.

For a new spring-boot app, I am looking to use Solace Java API and going through provided samples.

e.g. [HowToConsumePersistentMessageWithAutoAcknowledgement](https://github.com/SolaceSamples/solace-samples-java/blob/main/src/main/java/com/solace/samples/java/snippets/HowToConsumePersistentMessageWithAutoAcknowledgement.java) and [HelloWorld](https://github.com/SolaceSamples/solace-samples-java/blob/main/src/main/java/com/solace/samples/java/HelloWorld.java)

I noticed `receiveAsync` of `PersistentMessageReceiver` fetches waiting/pending messages in the queue and finishes the thread immediately, instead of waiting for a future message. `receiveAsync` call requires to be in a `while` loop if more messages are expected for future messages based on samples. I am not sure if using `while` loop is an elegant solution (was expecting something similar to `onMessage`).

Should I use `receiveAsync` in a `while` loop, with a flag pushed from app/spring bean `shutdown` ? Is my approach wrong? Please guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **HelloWorld** sample uses Direct messaging, so not applicable to your Persistent use-case.  (unless you want to use Direct messaging instead?)

This might be more relevent: [patterns/GuaranteedSubscriber](https://github.com/SolaceSamples/solace-samples-java/blob/main/src/main/java/com/solace/samples/java/patterns/GuaranteedSubscriber.java)

And the docs here: https://docs.solace.com/API-Developer-Online-Ref-Documentation/pubsubplus-java/com/solace/messaging/receiver/PersistentMessageReceiver.html

The behaviour you're describing sounds more like `receiveMessage(long timeOut)` with a timeout of 0.  With the `receiveAsync(MessageReceiver.MessageHandler messageHandler)` method, you pass in the MessageHandler, and that is what is triggered asynchronously (just like JMS `onMessage()` callback).  And it returns `void`.  So I'm not sure how you're getting a message from calling that method?

So yes, check the **GuaranteedSubscriber** sample above, hopefully it demonstrates Persistent async message handling.  And remember: best practices are to use *client* ACK (manually triggered by your app when done processing the message, from any thread... not auto ACK, which is super basic and just ACKs when the callback is finished.  (unless you're doing all your processing in the callback thread, which (also best practices) should be very minimal, otherwise use your own thread).

Comment: Thank you Aaron. Your response is helpful. That clarifies my misunderstanding.